# Solr config Woes -- solr running but not indexing

Tags: configuration, solr

I'm just getting started with Solr, running it from Tomcat6. I followed all the install instructions and the webapp seems to be running fine. I used curl to to send the sample data from the solr startup example, and the server seems to return what it is supposed to when someting is indexed successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">4</int></lst>
</response>
```

But when I got to check the index through the admin/stats interface, nothing has made it into the index. It hasn't even regeistered the request??

```
searcherName : Searcher@5cd73256 main 
caching : true 
numDocs : 0 
maxDoc : 0 
reader : SolrIndexReader{this=ec5aba9,r=ReadOnlyDirectoryReader@ec5aba9,refCnt=1,segments=0} 
readerDir : org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/home/tomcat6/solr/data/index 
indexVersion : 1266212874907 
openedAt : Fri Apr 15 13:46:52 EDT 2011 
registeredAt : Fri Apr 15 13:46:52 EDT 2011 
warmupTime : 0
```

I'm really curious at this line: readerDir : org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/home/tomcat6/solr/data/index

as this doesnt exist on the server, my index is located at /home/myhome/solr/data/index

I configured the solr home through the webapps web.xml env tag. And the proper home is displayed in the main admin screen

Any ideas how I might get my index working?

Thanks ahead of time.

--dm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to commit the new documents, e.g. after adding:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update -F stream.body=' <commit />'
```